# Desktop alarm clock/reminder/weather report application for Windows XP

Tags: windows, software-rec, desktop-gadget

I have a 7 inch netbook. I want to use it as a router. Windows XP installed on it. I configured everything and it is working as an access point now. I want to use its 7 inch screen as an alarm clock. I want to see my daily schedule, news.. etc. I do not want to interact with it. Everything should be automatic. Does anyone know a good application for this kind of purpose?

Comment: Netbook as a router? Do you have two network cards in it?

Comment: Ethernet interface and the wireless interface...yes 2 network cards. I found Google desktop gadgets suitable form most of the functions I want by the way